# Word 2013 not changing footer size

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, whitespace, line-spacing, footers

I'm trying to make the space at the bottom of the page smaller so I can fit more text into it. I tried setting the footer and header to really small numbers but it doesn't seem to make a difference. What's going on?

[image: screen shot of word]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The footer section can be altered by setting the `Margin` to `Narrow`, then adjusting the side ruler to place you wish. to start the line

[image]

It's odd you can't do it manually like the header, but this is all i found personally after a bit of my own research.

Comment: How do you adjust the margins in 2013?

Comment: check out [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCvyo36hohA) and [THIS.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/custom-margins-in-word-2013-RZ104090033.aspx)